# Notify other component from another component - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have this problem that can't be solved. I want to change the "LOGIN" text in my header component into "LOGOUT" text after I have successfully logged in using a Token.

```
login () {

    if(this.loginForm.valid){
        this.authenticationService.login(this.loginForm.value.username,this.loginForm.value.password)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        this.showError = false;
                        this.router.navigate(['']);
                    }
    }
}
```

In my AuthenticationService I have this function "isLoggedIn()" wherein it check if there's a token that was saved:

```
login(username,password){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

        return this.http.post(this.configEnvironment.url() + "oauth/access_token",
            JSON.stringify(
                {
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    grant_type: "password",
                    client_id: "xx",
                    client_secret: "xx"
                }
            ),
            { headers }
        )
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(res => {
            localStorage.setItem("access_token",res.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem("refresh_token",res.refresh_token);

            this.loggedIn = true;
        })
        .catch((err:Response) => {
            let error = {};
            error["message"] = err.json();
            error["status"] = err.status;

            return Observable.throw(error);

         });

     }

     isLoggedIn() {
         return this.loggedIn;
     }
```

Now, in my header component in constructor, I call is the isLoggedIn function in the AuthenticationService:

```
this.isLoggedIn = this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Log in</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/signup']" class="btn btn--red">Sign up</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
                <li><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
```

My problem is the HeaderComponent doesn't listen when the isLoggedIn value changes after the redirection of the LoginComponent.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a "best practice" or not, but bind directly to the `authenticationService.loggedIn` property.  That way as you login/logout, the `nav` will be updated

Comment: like this?
*ngIf="this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn()"

Comment: Not to the method, since once it's called it won't be updated again.  Bind to the `loggedIn` property you are referencing in that method instead of the method itself.  `authenticationService.loggedIn`.  Property bindings like that will update as the property is updated.  Binding to a method only does the binding one time.  Once the method is complete it doesn't go back and fire the method regularly to see if anything has changed

Comment: I try to access directly the property, but still no luck:

ngIf="!this.authenticationService.loggedIn"

Comment: Try dropping the `this.` from that...make it `*ngIf="authenticationService.loggedIn"`

Comment: I try to do that still luck :(

Comment: Are you sure you're getting to the `.map` where you change the value of `loggedIn`?  I'm doing this exact setup in the app I have open right now and it works like a charm

Comment: Yes Im sure because when I console log the value of loggedIn before I redirect to other pages is it returns true which is false when I initialised and also I can see the access_token and refresh_token in my chrome developer tools. And also when I refresh the browser, loggedIn returns true

Comment: Solved it bro, I put the instantiation of providers in app.module.ts. The problem in my previous code is that the AuthenticationService is initialized again in the providers of the HeaderComponent that's why it always return false

Comment: LOL I didn't even see that, I have a post about that exact issue somewhere in here, for the exact same reasons... Glad you got it figured out

Comment: Is this issue solved? I am facing same problem . I have tried using the subject to listen changes, but its something odd to me.